# aggregate mongodb search in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search, aggregation-framework, aggregate

my documents in mongodb collection :

```
{ 
  'id' : 'ID1',
  'status' : 'ST1',
  'logs' : [
    {
      'id' : 'ID2',
      'status_old' : 'ST2',
      'status_new' : 'ST3',
    },
    {
      'id' : 'ID3',
      'status_old' : 'ST3',
      'status_new' : 'ST4',
    }
  ]
},
{ 
  'id' : 'ID4',
  'status' : 'ST4',
  'logs' : [
    {
      'id' : 'ID5',
      'status_old' : 'ST2',
      'status_new' : 'ST3',
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to pass the documents through the following two filters

```
filter1 : 
where
   ( status    = 'ST1'  OR
    status_old = 'ST1'  OR
    status_new = 'ST1'  )
```

Then the answer obtained should be placed in the following filter (condition):

```
filter2 : 
where
   ( status    = 'ST2'  OR
    status_old = 'ST2'  OR
    status_new = 'ST2'  )
```

The answer is stated with two conditions and according to the documents provided above, the following is the case:

```
{ 
  'id' : 'ID1',
  'status' : 'ST1',
  'logs' : [
    {
      'id' : 'ID2',
      'status_old' : 'ST2',
      'status_new' : 'ST3',
    },
    {
      'id' : 'ID3',
      'status_old' : 'ST3',
      'status_new' : 'ST4',
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: `logs` is an array right? So would the filters match any item in the array ?

Comment: yes . logs is array , I edited the question

Comment: yes ,  filters match any item in the array AND status field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are not filtering out any elements from the `logs` array this looks like an aggregation with 2 `$match` stages with `$or` in it

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "status": "ST1"
        },
        {
          "logs.status_old": "ST1"
        },
        {
          "logs.status_new": "ST1"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "status": "ST2"
        },
        {
          "logs.status_old": "ST2"
        },
        {
          "logs.status_new": "ST2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VYpzgAUl6qa)

Comment: We also have other filters so that it is not crowded and complicated, it is not mentioned in the question, does this method work properly with other filters?

Comment: can you do some checks with some sample data in https://mongoplayground.net/p/VYpzgAUl6qa